# Remove/prevent future element to be loaded in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

For presentation purposes, I'm use a free web hosting service to show to my customers how their future website should be. ([Webhost](http://000webhost.com)) 
But webhost inserts scripts in bottom of code that shows popup in every first session.

My question is : ***How can I remove this popup or prevent it to be showed/loaded properly***

**COOKIE** :

```
a_visited_already    true    stats.hosting24.com    21 B    /    21/04/2016 à 13:20:43
```

**HTML-CSS / JAVASCRIPT** :

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.popup {
    display: block;
    width: 666px;
    height: 474px;
    background-image: url(http://stats.hosting24.com/popup/bg_popup.png);
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.popup a.close {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}
.ikuruzkrauti {
    margin: 30px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){$("#visas_style_div").bPopup({contentContainer:".ikuruzkrauti"});});
</script>
<div class="bModal __bPopup1" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); height: 100%; left: 0px; opacity: 0.7; position: fixed; top: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 9998; cursor: pointer;"></div>
<div id="visas_style_div" class="popup" style="left: 627px; position: absolute; top: 20px; z-index: 9999;"> <a class="close bClose" href=""></a>
    <div class="ikuruzkrauti"> <a href="http://www.hostinger.nl"> <img border="0" src="http://www.hostinger.nl/banners/nl/hostinger-600x400-2.gif"> </a> </div>
</div>
```

They use **bpopup** > [Link](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/)

```
/*********************************************************************************
 * @name: bPopup
 * @author: (c)Bjoern Klinggaard (http://dinbror.dk/bpopup - twitter@bklinggaard)
 * @version: 0.8.0.min
 *********************************************************************************/
```

Comment: Doesn't this go against the terms of service of the host?

Comment: there is other free host services [don't show popup]

Comment: @DaanMeijer - No - https://www.000webhost.com/includes/tos.php Ctrl+F "advertising" "Ads"

Comment: or if you have lot of customers buy one dedicated host .

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky I can't edit a cookie written by another domain...

Comment: @FastSnail  This a case of study for me for other js devs. I have dedicated hosts don't worry. Just answer if you have any solution for the problem as it

Comment: Does it help or is it unrelevant? https://www.000webhost.com/forum/customer-assistance/36192-ads-showing-why-pop-up-ad-my-site.html

Comment: they will remove your account if you try this kind of things .

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could override the bPopup method, like so:

```
$.fn.bPopup = function(){
    this.remove(); //removes the called div from the DOM
};
```

That is, assuming the jQuery they use for the popup purposes has been included in the page, at the time you have access to it.

If not, you could always choose to hide the popup:

```
body .popup {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: They include their own jquery in the last of my script